# CSS3 image aspect ratio lightbox

Tags: html, css

I have a problem creating a CSS3 ONLY lightbox. This is my current code:

```css
div#image-1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

div#image-1 > div {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

div#image-1 > div > img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-1">
  <div>
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/06/29/06/24/lotus-142028_960_720.jpg" alt="image-1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to force the image to be contained in the red div, preserving the aspect ratio so it could be auto-resized by window resizing.

I can do it without the red container like so:

```css
div#image-1 {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  padding:1%;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

div#image-1 > img {
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-1">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/06/29/06/24/lotus-142028_960_720.jpg" alt="image01" />
</div>
```

But I need to have the red container in order to add other stuff (like prev/next buttons, ...) and I need it to have the same height as the picture.

I don't want to set any width or height in pixel because I want it to be responsive and screen adaptive. I don't want to force upscalling by the browser so if the image is smaller than the window, I want the image to be displayed with it's default size, but if the image is larger, I want it to be contained in the red div.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use image as a background image with `background-position: contain;`

```css
div#image-1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

div#image-1 > div {
  background: transparent url() center / contain no-repeat;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-1">
  <div style="background-image: url(https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/06/29/06/24/lotus-142028_960_720.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've think of this possibility but the problem is I want to add previous/next buttons on each side of the image with a fixed width and the height of the image for a result as in the code below (the main reason I need the red container is when the image is smaller than the window)

```css
div#image-1 {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  padding:1%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

div#image-1 > img {
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}

div#image-1 > a {
  width:75px;
  height:100%; /*of the red div*/
  display:inline-block;
  border:2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-1">
  <a href="#previous"></a>
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/06/29/06/24/lotus-142028_960_720.jpg" alt="image01" />
  <a href="#next"></a>
</div>
```